# How to make the background change color smoothly in rainbow style?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm using P5.js library and I want to make the background of the canvas change color in rainbow style smoothly and continuously.

How can I do this? Thanks a lot in advance

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the HSB `colorMode`. This allows you to basically "cycle" through the color wheel by using numbers from 0 to 360 (ie specify a degree on the color wheel). Using this idea, you can draw many rectangles on your canvas, spanning from the top of the canvas to the bottom (amount of rectangle specified by `inc`). Each rectangle will have a particular color.
Thus, joining all these rectangles will allow you to create a gradient-like effect.

By continuously providing an offset to your color (and restricting it within the bounds or 0 to 360) you can cycle through the color wheel.

See code below:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

let cOffset = 0;
function draw() {
    const inc = height/100;
    colorMode(HSB);

    for(let y = 0; y < height; y += inc) {
        let h = y / height * 360;
        fill(abs(h-cOffset)%360, 100, 100);
        noStroke();
        rect(0, y-inc, width, y);
    }

    cOffset += 5;
}
```

See working version here:

https://editor.p5js.org/NickParsons/sketches/1xfjY-ZoE